# Bound of iterations for Jacobi / Gauss - Seidel / SOR

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Given a linear system of equations there is the standard way to solve it by applying one of the iterative methods mentioned in the title like this :

$$ x^{k+1} = G*x^k + c$$

where $G$ is the iterative matrix whose spectral radius should be less than one for the method to converge.

Given that the condition above stands how can one calculate the upper/lower bound of iterations needed when it comes to Jacobi / GS / SOR for a specific tolerance say $0.5*10^{-6}$?

Does it have something to do with the fact that : $$\frac{||e^k||_a}{||e^0||_a}\le ||G^k||_a$$ where $a =1 ,2,\infty$ and $e^x$ refers to the $x_{th}$ error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These methods correspond to the application of the fixed point method to the problem $x = G x + c$. This gives you estimates like
$$
\| x^{(k)} -z\| \leq L^k \|x^{(0)}-z\|
$$

or

$$
\| x^{(k)} -z\| \leq \frac{L^k}{1-L}\|x^{(1)}-x^{(0)}\|
$$

where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant for the iteration function, which can be bounded by the norm of the Jacobian matrix, in this case $\|G\|$.

So the answer is yes, it does have something to do with the inequality you mention, although the a posteriori estimates are more convenient, unless you have some specific bound on $\|e^{(0)}\|$.

Comment: Scrolling through my notes I encountered a formula which is presented as a not so accurate approximation of the iterations needed for convergence : $$ k = \frac{-log_{10}(ρ)}{-log_{10}(ρ(G))}$$  where $ρ$ should be the desired tolerance I guess.Does this formula stand ?

Comment: @RookieCookie The formula you mention corresponds to use the firs inequality I showed, using the 2- norm, setting $L = \rho(G)$ and further assuming that $\|x^{(0)}-z\|_2 < 1$. Your formula is not well written though... it should be $$k \ge \dfrac{\log (\varepsilon)}{\log (\rho(G))}$$, where $\varepsilon$ is the tolerance and $\rho(G)$ is the spectral radius of $G$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it :)